# Vaadin dynamically reflect changed data to all users' screens

Tags: java, push, vaadin7

I am trying to dynamically reflect the changes of the data to all logged in users' screens.

There are items being added to the database or one of their attributes is being changed by users or by scheduled tasks(cron-jobs).

What I want to do is reflecting those changes to all logged-in users' screens without a need of page refresh. This includes certain parts of all screens. One part is left menu side of all screens, the other one is table contents.

I am able to do that for one logged-in user via re assigning the changed datasource to the table and re building the left-side menu after re-assignment of the datasource. But this is only for the current user. I need to change all user screens which are currently in use at that moment.

I have checked Vaadin PUSH but could not really relate to it.

How can I do that with Vaadin?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/BroadcastingMessagesToOtherUsers.html

In short, you can use the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to notify all the UIs about changes in the database. You also need to enable push and modify the UI using the `UI.access(Runnable)` method.